# Button can't change value of corresponding input

Tags: javascript, html, cart

### The Problem:

I can't seem to be able to get a list of buttons to change the value of their corresponding inputs.

I'm trying to code a cart system for my website, pretty standard. It involves a list of item, each of which have a section that includes two buttons for adding or subtracting the quantity of its corresponding item. These buttons surround the input that displays the current quantity (disabled so that the user must use the buttons to control it).

Everything is working, but I can't seem to figure out how to target the corresponding input of a button that is clicked so that it will change the value of that specific input.

### What I've Tried:

I've figured out that if I add a [0] at the end of the "quantityInputs" variable then it will target the first input in the list, makes sense. But I don't want it to only target the first input, I want it to target the input that the button is associated with. Even then, when I test the plus button it only updates the input one time to 2 and then stops, which I only know because I'm printing the value to the console - it doesn't actually change the display on the webpage.

I've considered using a for loop to get the position of the input, but I'm not sure how to incorporate that into the code in order for it to work with the for loop that gets the position of the plus or minus buttons, or if that will even work.

Can anyone please help me out? I'd really appreciate it.

### My Code:

**HTML:**

```js
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
  changeQuantity()
}

function changeQuantity() {
  var buttonUps = document.getElementsByClassName('item-quantity-up')

  console.log('There are ' + buttonUps.length + ' plus buttons total.') // Tells you how many plus buttons there are.

  for (var i = 0; i < buttonUps.length; i++) { // Get the positions of each plus button.
    var button = buttonUps[i]
    button.addEventListener('click', addQuantity) // When a plus button is clicked, run the addQuantity function.
  }

  var buttonDowns = document.getElementsByClassName('item-quantity-down')

  console.log('There are ' + buttonDowns.length + ' minus buttons total.') // Tells you how many minus buttons there are.

  for (var i = 0; i < buttonDowns.length; i++) { // Get the positions of each minus button.
    var button = buttonDowns[i]
    button.addEventListener('click', subQuantity) // When a minus button is clicked, run the subQuantity function.
  }
}

function addQuantity(event) {

  var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-quantity') // Needs an index such as [0] in order to return a real number.
  var inputValue = parseInt(quantityInputs.value) // Turns the value into an integer.
  var max = quantityInputs.max // Retrieves the max value for the input.

  if (inputValue >= max) {
    inputValue = inputValue // If the quantity is greater than or equal to the max, then don't change the quantity.
  } else {
    inputValue = inputValue + 1 // If the quantity is less than the max, then add 1 to the quantity.
    console.log(inputValue)
  }
}

function subQuantity(event) {
  var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-quantity') // Needs an index such as [0] in order to return a real number.
  var inputValue = parseInt(quantityInputs.value) // Turns the value into an integer.
  var min = quantityInputs.min // Retrieves the min value for the input.

  if (inputValue <= min) {
    inputValue = inputValue // If the quantity is less than or equal to the min, then don't change the quantity.
  } else {
    inputValue = inputValue - 1 // If the quantity is greater than the min, then subtract one from the quantity.
    console.log(inputValue)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cart-quantity-field">
  <button class="item-quantity-down">-</button>
  <input class="cart-item-quantity" type="number" min="1" max="20" value="1" disabled>
  <button class="item-quantity-up">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `event.currentTarget` will contain the element that was clicked on. You can use this to find the corresponding input. `event.currentTarget.nextElementSibling` is the element after the button, `event.currentTarget.previousElementSibling` is the element before it.

Comment: @Barmar So if I understand correctly I should implement that for the "quantityInputs" variable instead of getting the document via class name?

Comment: Right, because the class name refers to all the elements with that class, not just the one next to the button.

Comment: @Barmar Great thank you so much! I have one more question, though. That did help me target the correct input, but now every time I try to add 1 to the input it gets stuck at 2 and just keeps resetting back to 1 with every button press. Any guesses on what could be causing this?

Comment: use `parseInt(quantityInput.max)`?

Comment: @Barmar Believe it or not I had just changed it to that but it doesn't seem to have made a difference. Could it have anything to do with the quantity that the input is displaying not actually changing when a button is clicked?

Comment: Your `addQuantity` function never assigns to `.value` to change the input value.

Comment: @Barmar I believe the "inputValue" variable accomplishes that, is that not the right place to put it?

Comment: No. `inputValue` contains the value that was read from the input, it's not an alias for `quantityInput.value`. Assigning to the variable doesn't assign to the input.

Comment: @Barmar It's working now! Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the correct input field by doing the following:

- On quantity-button click:

  - locate the clicked button's parent element
  - inside that parent, look for input with the correct class name
  - decide whether the button clicked should add or subtract one
  - add +1 or -1 respectively to the current value of the input

```js
const allQuantityBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity-btn");

Array.from(allQuantityBtns).forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", e => {
    const inputToChange = e.target.parentElement.querySelector(".cart-item-quantity");
    
    const plusOrMinusOne = e.target.classList.contains("item-quantity-up") ? 1 : -1;
    const newValue = parseInt(inputToChange.value) + plusOrMinusOne;
    
    // validate newValue here. Eg: is it allowed to be smaller than zero?
    
    inputToChange.value = newValue;
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="cart-quantity-field">
  <button class="item-quantity-down quantity-btn">-</button>
  <input class="cart-item-quantity" type="number" min="1" max="20" value="1" disabled>
  <button class="item-quantity-up quantity-btn">+</button>
</div>
```

Note: you may wish to implement some validation:

- stop the quantity from being too large or small before modifying the input's value